# Is it possible to withdraw LBP using Revolut in Lebanon?

Tags: lebanon, revolut

I'm planning to travel to Lebanon in next couple of months. From what I read on Internet, cash is the only trusted mean of payment.

However, I checked Revolut rates (I own the card) and it appears their rates are very close to black market rate.[[source]](https://www.revolut.com/currency-converter/). Also it's possible to spend/withdraw LBP according to their website. [[source]](https://help.revolut.com/help/card-payments-withdrawals/getting-started-with-card-payments/what-currencies-are-supported-for-spending/)

So in principle if I use Revolut card to withdraw LBP (in an ATM that accepts Mastercard or Visa), I should be able to get LBP at a close rate similar to unofficial markets. I'm not looking for a super precise conversion. As long as it's (+/-) 5% of black market, it's fine for me. I just don't want to carry euro around with me.

Am I being too stupid for believing this?

Comment: I have done it (withdrawing LBP with Revolut) but it was a few years ago (before the currency crisis and explosion in Beirut) so probably not a very useful answer for someone travelling today. Note that, in Lebanon, local banks / ATM operators typically charge a fee for using a Revolut card (or, presumably, any foreign card). That's a on top of any currency exchange spread and fees the card issuer is charging and even if you opt out of dynamic currency conversion.